# If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ be the roots of the polynomial $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s$, prove the following.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ be the roots of the polynomial $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s$, show that $$(1+\alpha^2)(1+\beta^2)(1+\gamma^2)(1+\delta^2)=(1-q+s)^2+(p-r)^2.$$

I have tried putting

\begin{align}P(1)&=(\alpha-1)(\beta-1)(\gamma-1)(\delta-1)=1+p+q+r+s\\P(-1)&=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)(\delta+1)=1-p+q-r+s.\end{align}

Then \begin{align}P(1)P(-1)&=(\alpha^2-1)(\beta^2-1)(\gamma^2-1)(\delta^2-1)\\&=(1+p+q+r+s)(1-p+q-r+s)=(1+q+s)^2-(p+r)^2\end{align}

Somehow it does not match the statement given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You correctly computed 
$$
(\alpha^2-1)(\beta^2-1)(\gamma^2-1)(\delta^2-1)=(1+q+s)^2-(p+r)^2
$$
only that this is not what was asked for.

But you were close: $\alpha^2+1 = (\alpha-i)(\alpha+i)$ etc, and therefore
$$
 (1+\alpha^2)(1+\beta^2)(1+\gamma^2)(1+\delta^2) = P(i) P(-i)
$$
which expands to
$$
(1-ip-q+ir+s)(1+ip-q-ir+s) = (1-q+s)^2+(p-r)^2 \, .
$$

Comment: Much neater solution!

Comment: This was really good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Denoting $\alpha=x_1$, $\beta=x_2$, $\gamma=x_3$ and $\delta=x_4$, we have $$\small\prod_{i=1}^4(1+x_i^2)-\prod_{i=1}^4(1-x_i^2)=\small2(x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)+2(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)$$ so taking out a factor of $x_1x_2x_3x_4$ from the first term in brackets, $$\prod_{i=1}^4(1+x_i^2)=2\left(\prod_{i=1}^4x_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^4\frac1{x_i}\right)+2\sum_{i=1}^4x_i+\prod_{i=1}^4(1-x_i^2)$$ which is evaluable by [Vieta's formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html). For the sum of reciprocals, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914440/on-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial).

Comment: Sorry but I can't make heads or tails of it. Looking at the post it seems like differentiation is involved somewhere. And can you please tell me where to start to understand this "Vieta's formulas" coz I'm a newbie to Advance math like these.

Comment: Added link to the formulas. A lot of sums and products, but no calculus involved, as per the tags of your post.

Comment: Oh Thanks ^_^ I'll go through the links. I just realized my book also has it. (That's where I found this question). This formula is given in the later articles on the book.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using Transformation of equation:

We have $$x^4+qx^2+s=-x(px^2+r)$$

Squaring both sides

$$(x^2)^4+q^2(x^2)+s^2+2q(x^2)^3+2qs(x^2)+2s(x^2)^2=x^2(p^2(x^2)^2+r^2+2pr(x^2))$$

Replacing $x^2+1=y$

$$(y-1)^4+q^2(y-1)^2+s^2+2q(y-1)^3+2qs(y-1)+2s(y-1)^2=(y-1)(p^2(y-1)^2+r^2+2pr(y-1))$$

$$\iff y^4+\cdots+1+q^2+s^2-2q-2qs+2s+p^2+r^2-2pr=0$$

Using Vieta's formula $$\prod_{j=1}^4y_j=\dfrac{1+q^2+s^2-2q-2qs+2s+p^2+r^2-2pr}1=(1-q+s)^2+(p-r)^2$$

Answer (score -2):

Your approach ends up proving $(α^2 - 1)(β^2 - 1)(γ^2 - 1)(δ^2 - 1) = (1 - q + s)^2 - (p - r)^2$. This means we will have to do something with that minus sign and to do that we can use the identity $(x + ιy)(x - ιy) = x^2 + y^2$. Putting $P(ι)$, and $P(-ι)$ you can easily solve the problem with the same approach.